# Why var.constant is not allowed for an enum class?

Tags: c++, c++11, enum-class

Suppose we have an enum class:

```
enum class E
{
    constant
};
```

To refer to the enumerator in E, we can write `E::constant`, while the following is illegal:

```
E e;
e.constant;
```

But consider this:

```
struct S
{
    enum {constant};
};
```

Both `S::constant` and `s.constant` are legal, wouldn't it be more consistent to allow `e.constant` for an enum class? Is the inability intentional?

Comment: It wouldn't make much sense because `e` is an instance of an `enum`. As such, it can only hold one value. `constant` is not a *member* of the enumeration. It is one of the possible values it can hold.

Comment: the variable `e` doesn't have to hold the values, the values are something like static member constants.

Comment: `e` can only hold one value. The values are nothing like static member constants. That is the point.

Comment: Can you find a case where `e.constant` is needed. I.e. not covered by `E::constant`?

Comment: @RedX in the case that E is deep in some namespace/class hierarchy, e.g. `Ns1::Ns2::C1::C2::E`, then you have to write `e == Ns1::Ns2::C1::C2::E::constant`, so I think it's nice to have `e == e.constant`.

Comment: I think that `decltype(e)::constant` would solve that problem.

Comment: @RedX that's true but still not as simple as `e.constant`.

Comment: But `e.constant` makes no sense, so would be confusing to allow.

Comment: @juanchopanza that argument also applies to static data members, like `s.constant` I shown in the example, but since C++ allows this syntax anyway, I think it'd be better to make it consistent.

Comment: The key word being *member*. An enumeration's value is not a member. It is one of the set allowed values an instance of the enumeration can hold.